# last and first word in a string c#

Tags: c#, string

i need to print the first and the last word in a string here is what i've tried

```
        Console.WriteLine("please enter a string");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        string first = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(" "));
        string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(' '),str.Length-1);
        Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last);
```

when i run the code this massage appear

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
> Parameter name: length
> at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
> at ConsoleApp1.Tar13.Main() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Tar13.cs:line 16

i dont know what is the problem

Comment: Substring doesn't need the end index, but the length of the substring

Comment: use this for the last word: `string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(' '), str.Length - str.LastIndexOf(' '));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is homework, don't hand this in unless you really understand it, have done LINQ (or have a supervisor that approves of off-piste learning and you're prepared to acknowledge you got outside assistance/did background learning) and are willing to [explain it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-5.0) if asked:

```
    Console.WriteLine("please enter a string");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] bits = str.Split();
    Console.WriteLine(bits.First() + " " + bits.Last());
```

For a non-LINQ version:

```
    Console.WriteLine("please enter a string");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    string first = str.Remove(str.IndexOf(' '));
    string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last);
```

Bear in mind that these will crash if there are no spaces in the string - the Split version won't

Look at String [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-5.0) and [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)

If you want to robust things up so it doesn't crash:

```
    Console.WriteLine("please enter a string");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    if(str.Contains(" ")){
      string first = str.Remove(str.IndexOf(' '));
      string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
      Console.WriteLine(first + " " + last);
    }
```

I'll leave a "what might we put in an *else*?" in that last code block, as an exercise for you :)

Comment: and if the string ends in space?

Comment: @KeithNicholas not part of the specification/trim it/we could keep going like that all night/what color do you want the bikeshed

Answer (score 2):

you can split the string and get first and last...

```
   var s = str.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
   if(s.Length >= 2) 
   {
    var first = s.First();
    var last = s.Last();
    Console.WriteLine($"{first} {last}");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In *general case* when sentence can contain *punctuation*, not necessary *English* letters you can try *regular expressions*. Let's define

> **Word** is non empty sequence of *letters* and *apostrophes*

And so we have

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  private static (string first, string last) Solve(string value) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
      return ("", "");

    var words = Regex
      .Matches(value, @"[\p{L}']+")
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(m => m.Value)
      .ToArray();

    return words.Length > 0
      ? (words[0], words[words.Length - 1])
      : ("", ""); 
  }
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Simple string",                 // Simple Smoke Test
    "Single",                        // Single word which is both first an last
    "",                              // No words at all; let's return empty strings
    "words, punctuations: the end.", // Punctuations
    "Русская (Russian) строка!",     // Punctuations, non-English words
  };

  var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-30} :: {Solve(test)}"));

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Simple string                  :: (Simple, string)
Single                         :: (Single, Single)
                               :: (, )
words, punctuations: the end.  :: (words, end)
Русская (Russian) строка!      :: (Русская, строка)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last and first-word try to do the following:

```cs
string sentence = "Hello World"; //Sentence
string first = sentence.Split(" ")[0]; //First word
string last = sentence.Split(" ")[sentence.Split(" ").Length -1]; //Last word
Console.WriteLine(first + " "+ last);
```